# Spring @DateTimeFormat doesn't seem to validate ISO dates

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm facing strange behavior, not sure whether it's a bug or a feature. Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/delayedtemplates", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public void delayedFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                              @RequestParam(name = "siteduedate")
                                      @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
                                      Date dueDate
) {
...
}
```

The issue, that if I enter the `siteduedate` parameter as 20018-08-09 it's still parsed as a valid ISO8601 date. More than that, it's pushed into Postgres as a valid date! Is there a way to prevent such behavior?
Spring boot version 1.5.2.RELEASE

Comment: According to Wikipedia `20018-08-09` seems to be a correct date format going by ISO8601 standards. Isn't this so ?

Comment: From what I see in Wikipedia is *An expanded year representation [±YYYYY] must have an agreed-upon number of extra year digits beyond the four-digit minimum, and it must be prefixed with a + or − sign*. More than that, if I look at the javadocs of `DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE`: *DATE
public static final DateTimeFormat.ISO DATE
The most common ISO Date Format yyyy-MM-dd, e.g. "2000-10-31".*

Comment: And your date is in correct format. Did I understand something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

For me the following combination works for either serializing/ deserializing using Spring MVC.

DTO:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") 
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") 
private final LocalDate myDate;
```

I suggest to use Java 8 Date/Time classes.